# Slow connection from EC2 to RDS while the local connection to RDS is fine

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have an AWS account with EC2 and RDS. Both of them are on the same VPC. 
I setup through Elastic Beanstalk.
They both have shared security groups and I CAN connect to my RDS (MySQL) from my EC2 instance (PHP) successfully. However, it is extremely slow (90 seconds).

If I am connecting from MySQL workbench at home or even through my local host it is nice and responsive (237ms).

I don't know what else to check or to change to get EC2 and RDS working fast.

In the case if anyone wonders, this is the the code I'm using to test the connection time:

```
echo date('H:i:s').PHP_EOL;
$host = $_ENV["RDS_HOSTNAME"];
$user = $_ENV["RDS_USERNAME"];
$pass = $_ENV["RDS_PASSWORD"];
$db = $_ENV["RDS_DB_NAME"];
echo "Environment variables set: ".date('H:i:s').PHP_EOL;
try{
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    echo "First Complete: ".date('H:i:s').PHP_EOL;
    mysqli_select_db($con, $_ENV["RDS_DB_NAME"]);
    echo "Second Complete: ".date('H:i:s').PHP_EOL;
}catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    print_r(mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: What does `dig <rds hostname>` output from the EC2 instance? How long does it take to fetch a result?

Comment: The environmental variables take no time at all to fetch (same timestamp before and after).  The output is the end_point for the RDS database.  It's the same as what I use to connect from mySQL Workbench.   I haven't really messed with querying yet because the connection is taking so long.

Comment: I'm not asking about environment variables. I'm wondering if DNS lookups are your issue when you try to *use* those environment variables in `mysqli_connect`. Again, what does `dig <rds hostname>` output from your EC2 instance **and how long does it take**? (I'm also interested if you're getting the internal or external IP for the RDS endpoint.)

Comment: OH!  I'm sorry, I'm such a software person I sometimes miss configuration questions.  Do I need to putty into EC2 to run the dig name?

Comment: Yep, Putty'd do fine.

Comment: 5 IN CNAME ec2-13-59-102-56.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com.
ec2-13-59-102-56.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com. 20 IN A 172.31.31.86
    ;; Query time: 30 msec
    ;; SERVER: 172.31.0.2#53(172.31.0.2)
    ;; WHEN: Fri Jun 22 01:03:00 2018
    ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 127

Is this what you are asking for?  I had trouble with putty but I got it as soon as I came back from a break

Comment: I double checked what I queried and what I actually have stored as the host name when I did "dig"  returned


elasticbeanstalk.com. 20 IN A 52.14.117.189



;; Query time: 0 msec

;; SERVER: 172.31.0.2#53(172.31.0.2)
;; WHEN: Fri Jun 22 01:08:23 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 73

Comment: I'm looking for the output of `dig <rds hostname>`. Your RDS hostname should be something like `foo.bar.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: <<>>DiG 9.8.2rcl-RedHat-9.8.2-0.62.rcl.57.amznl <<>> <rds hostname>
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
SIAgency.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com.  7 IN A 52.14.117.189

Query time: 0 msec
Server: 172.31.0.2#53(172.31.0.2)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @ceejayoz for his patience with me and Putty.  I realized I had my RDS HOSTNAME Environment variable pointed at my Elastic Beanstalk URL instead of my RDS instance.  This likely had it stuck in a redirect.

I just tried again and the timestamp differences start to finish was 0!

Comment: That'll do it, heh. Glad you got it sorted out.